# Date in typescript in my angular 2 application

Tags: date, typescript

I'm in the middle of making some test data to my views, before I make the API calls to the API application.

In a service in my angular 2 application, I have created a interface which looks like this:

```
export interface amendmentBookings {
    bookingNumber: string;
    outboundDate: Date;
    returnDate: Date;
    route: string;
    Passengers: string;    
    vehicleType: string;
}
```

I have also created an array which must consist of type to this interface. The code looks like this:

```
var bookings: amendmentBookings[] = [
    {
        bookingNumber: "123456789",
        outboundDate: 
        returnDate:
        route: "Dünkirchen - Dover",
        vehicleType: "Car 1.85m x 4.5m",
        Passengers: "1 adult and 1 child"
    },
]
```

How can I insert a date in my test data?

I have tried with the new Date() which you use in javascript, like this:

```
new Date("February 4, 2016 10:13:00");
```

But that does not work..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try in your browser's console that the following JS code works so it should work in TypeScript too:

```
 var bookings = [{
     bookingNumber: "123456789",
     outboundDate: new Date("February 4, 2016 10:13:00"),
     returnDate: new Date("February 4, 2016 10:13:00"),
     route: "Dünkirchen - Dover",
     vehicleType: "Car 1.85m x 4.5m",
     Passengers: "1 adult and 1 child"
}];

console.log(bookings)
```

Please add an error you get.

Comment: Well.. I found the problem.. for some reason, it worked when I closed down Visual Studio Code and opened it again.